# Waiting for a long-running SQL Server query to complete in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am running a PHP script that connects to an SQL Server database. The purpose is to create billing statements for customers and involves running a query that can take about 30 to 60 seconds to get the relevant data into a temp table, then generating PDF files from that data using FPDF (a PHP tool for creating PDFs).

As I discovered, when running a time-consuming query in PHP it is basically an asynchronous process, although PHP generally is synchronous. So if I try to access the data in the temp table immediately after the query that creates it, that will fail. To prevent that, I tried running the query, then running a loop that checks for existence of the temp table. However, for some reason this loop never exits, though if I go into SQL Server I can see that the temp table has been created. Here is the code and I would like to figure out why this loop doesn't exit.

Another alternative is to skip the loop and just put sleep(120) or some other value that is longer than the query ever takes, but I don't feel totally comfortable with that and would prefer to get the loop to work.

```
$temp_table='temp_statement_' . date('mdyhis');
$SQL="select .... into " . $temp_table . " from .... ";  // the actual query code doesn't matter for this purpose
sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL);

// Loop to check for existence of the table
$count1=0;
$SQL1="SELECT COUNT(*) COUNT1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='" . $temp_table . "'";
while ($count1==0) {
  $qry1=sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL1);
  $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry1, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH);
  $count1=intval($row1['COUNT1']); // after the table is created, this should be 1
  sleep(1);
}
sleep(5); // allow a bit of extra time before proceeding

// After temp table with relevant data is created, generate PDF files from that data
$SQL1="SELECT DISTINCT ID_NO FROM " . $temp_table;
$qry1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL1);
while($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($qry1, SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH)) {
 // Generate PDF files here
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect: _As I discovered, when running a time-consuming query in PHP it is basically an asynchronous process, although PHP generally is synchronous._ SQL Statements are synchronous otherwise ACID goes out the door.

Comment: I would suggest you do some basic error checking to see what's actually happening.  `sqlsrv_query()` will return `false` if there was a problem and you're not actually checking for that condition. When it returns `false` you'll want to follow up with something like `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` to halt the program and report the error message(s). When you don't get `false` back you'll need to consume the records from the returned cursor object before you try executing another query on the same connection. You may even need to prefix your select into statement with `SET NOCOUNT ON;`.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here. None of the queries have errors, and the temp table is always created.  If I eliminate the loop and just put in a long sleep() after the query that creates that table, everything after that works fine. The question is why is the loop never exiting.

Comment: Please re-read my comments. You are neither testing nor consuming the results of `sqlsrv_query()` properly. Even though `select-into` may not be returning any result sets, it will returning a rowcount... what are you doing about that?

Comment: Test - debug your query and code outside of the while loop after you see that the temp table is created.  When it woks for sure, then add the loop.  Add print statements to inspect the value of $count1, as this is where the problem lies.  Debug.And check error status returns like @AlwaysLearning commented.

Comment: I didn't really know what you meant by "consuming" the records - I haven't heard that terminology before. But it got me to think that maybe by just storing the return value of the first query in a variable, that would solve the problem. And it worked! Instead of just `sqlsrv_query($conn, $SQL)` I used `$qry=sqlsrv_query($conn,$SQL)` and then the loop and the sleep() were no longer necessary. I'm not sure I understand why that makes a difference so if you have an explanation I'd like to hear it.

Comment: "involves running a query that can take about 30 to 60 seconds to get the relevant data into a temp table".  Something about this statement is wrong from a performance standpoint.  You only care about your temp table?